# Error while trying to stack raster layers

Tags: r

I am running a code developed by someone. I am trying to create the raster stack. When I run the code, it gives me this error

> Error in .local(.Object, ...) : Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band
>   = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)

```
gcmDir <- "C:\\Users\\sangay\\Documents\\Eco Crop Modelling\\Future Scenario\\Results\\RCP8.5\\analyses\\runs-future" # directory where different results exists that are to be ensembled
outFolder <- "C:\\Users\\sangay\\Documents\\Eco Crop Modelling\\Future Scenario\\Results\\RCP8.5Assembled" # directory to save results
rsn <- "MaizeAssembled" # full name of the results to be ensembled

if (!file.exists(outFolder)) {dir.create(outFolder)}

gcmList <- list.files(gcmDir)
for (gcm in gcmList) {
    cat(gcm, "/n")
    rDir <- paste(gcmDir, "/", gcm, sep="") # gcm location for future data
    rs <- raster(paste(rDir, "/", rsn, ".tif", sep=""))
    if (gcm == gcmList[1]) {
        gcmstack <- c(rs)
    } else {
        gcmstack <- c(gcmstack, rs)
    }
}

###I am including the error below:
*bcc_csm1_1 /n
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 
Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype =   "RasterLayer",  : 
Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)
gcmstack <- stack(gcmstack)*

## again the code starts below:
# Stack averages
avg <- mean(gcmstack)

#Stack standar deviation
fun <- function(x) { sd(x) }
std <- calc(gcmstack, fun)


avg <- writeRaster(avg, paste(outFolder, "/", rsn, "_avg.asc", sep=""),        format="ascii", overwrite=T)
std <- writeRaster(std, paste(outFolder, "/", rsn, "_std.asc", sep=""), format="ascii", overwrite=T)
```

Can anyone help me out the solve this problem? I have tried myself but can't figure out anything. I am a novice in R.

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Try building your file paths with the `file.path` command. So instead of `paste(gcmDir, "/", gcm, sep="")` you would do `file.path(gcmDir, gcm)`.

Comment: And `rs <- raster(paste(rDir, "/", rsn, ".tif", sep=""))` would be better as `rs <- raster(file.path(rDir, paste0(rsn, ".tif")))`

Comment: Sorry I still get the same problem using your suggestion..any further suggestion? Thank you

Comment: It's hard to help you with your problem because it is not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The error suggests your file `MaizeAssembled.tif` doesn't exist, is this the case?

Comment: Thank you so much C. Braun for helping me out. Finally I was able to resolve the issue.